# Need to move the next iteration of outer loop

Tags: ruby

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[100,101,102,103,104]

a.each do |i|
    b.each do |j|
        if j.eql?101
            next            
        end
    end
end
```

The next keyword in the above loop perform the next operation for inner loop, But I do want to perform the next operation of outer loop, what should I do?

Comment: you should use `break` when if condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[100,101,102,103,104]

a.each do |i|
  b.each do |j|
    if j.eql? 101
        break
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perhaps inner loop may be better like: `b.each { |j| break if j == 101 }`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `break`, you could use [`take_while`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while):

```
a.each do |i|
  b.take_while { |j| j != 101 }.each do |j|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I like how it reads. `take_until` would be even better, but we don't have that method.